# Python Dictonaries - Appending new Dictionaries with same keys without deleting the last

Tags: python

A simple example for what I want to do:

I have two (or more) dictionaries with same keys:

```
a = {"animal" : "elefant"}
b = {"animal" : "dog"}
```

and I would like to have a new dictionary containing both, looking like this:

```
c = { {"animal" : "elefant"}, {"animal" : "dog"} }
```

of course, I have multiple dictionaries and I would like to add them to one big dictionary for example in a for loop.

I don't want to map all values to one key, maybe its not a dictionary of dictionarys, but a list of dictionaries? (This is why I am asking..)

Comment: Are you aware that you have a set and not a dict? Can you prove an example of what happens to c if you add a new dict like this ? `{"fruit": "banana"}`

Comment: `c` is not a dictionary but a set of dictionaries, which doesn't exist since dicts aren't hashable. What is your expected _valid_ output ?

Comment: you mean to have animal as key and a _list_ of animals as value probably?

Comment: I suggest to use a list `c =[ {"animal" : "elefant"}, {"animal" : "dog"} ]`. I think that  it is more easy to use them

Comment: Hm, ok I thought this was possible.. What I have is a lot of dictionaries containing  same keys with different values, and I would like to have something like that: c = { dict1, dict2, ... }, something like "append" just for dictionaries

Comment: please [edit] your question. Comments aren't as useful as question edits from the question asker

Comment: so `c = [a,b]` what's the problem?

Comment: if I try for example to do that: c = [ ] then c.append(a) it doesn't work .. So my guess was that this is not possible with dictionaries?

Comment: of course it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the same key to multiple values with a `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = {"animal" : "elefant"}
b = {"animal" : "dog"}

d = defaultdict(list)
d["animal"].append(a["animal"])
d["animal"].append(b["animal"])

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'animal': ['elefant', 'dog']})
```

If you want to keep the same dictionaries together in nested lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [{"animal": "elefant"}, {"animal": "dog"}, {"human": "John"}, {"human": "Jane"}]

data = defaultdict(list)
for dic in lst:
    k = tuple(dic)[0]
    data[k].append(dic)

print(list(data.values()))
# [[{'animal': 'elefant'}, {'animal': 'dog'}], [{'human': 'John'}, {'human': 'Jane'}]]
```

Or you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

key_func = lambda x: tuple(x)[0]

print([list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(lst, key=key_func), key=key_func)])
# [[{'animal': 'elefant'}, {'animal': 'dog'}], [{'human': 'John'}, {'human': 'Jane'}]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was searching for, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could use the extend or update methods:

```
first = {1: 1, 2: 2}
second = {2: 'ha!', 3: 3}
first.update(second)
```

output:

```
first:
{1: 1, 2: 'ha!', 3: 3}
```

this is the default, but it can be implemented differently to turn a dictionary in to a dictionary of dictionaries

## edit:

```
def update_without_overwriting(d, x):
    dict.update({k: v for k, v in x.items() if k not in d})
```

to get around any potential overwriting

Comment: that doesn't work, it overwrites the old keys

Comment: the extend method doesnt

Comment: Even in your own example it is overwriting the value stored against 2... it can't _not_, this is a fundamental property of dictionaries

Comment: check the last edit